# filter apostrophe out of xml variables

Tags: php, mysql, xml

hi, i work with a small xml script that filters all entries in a database. My problem is, that in the names of some xml strings are apostrophs that i need to filter in a mysql database. but when i run the script, all data es there, except for them with apostrophe. heres my code:

```
include 'new.php'; //include xml file
$haus = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

´
foreach ($haus->features as $features) {
    foreach ($features->properties as $properties) { 
       $name = $properties->name;
        $insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO locations (name)
                                VALUES ('$name')");
        echo $mysqli->affected_rows;
    }
}
```

is there a way to get the apostrophe in the database with php?

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string() ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a prepared statement which means you don't have to worry about quotes. This will also protect you from SQL Injection. There will also be a slight performance benefit because you can create the prepared statement once, then execute it many times without having to send the whole query to the MySQL engine over and over.

```
$count = 0; // if you want to check how many rows were inserted

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO locations (name) VALUES (?)')){
    foreach ($haus->features as $features) {
        foreach ($features->properties as $properties) { 
            $name = $properties->name;

            $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $count++;
            }
        }
    } 
}

echo 'total inserted: ' . $count;
```